# reexport a function from a module

Tags: haskell

I have a module like this

```
module A where

import qualified Data.Maybe as Maybe

fromMaybe = Maybe.fromMaybe
```

Is it possible to re-export just some functions from `Data.Maybe`? I don't want to re-export the entire `Data.Maybe` module, but just some functions, like `fromMaybe`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can selectively re-export functions:

```
module A (
  module A,
  Maybe.fromMaybe ) where 

import qualified Data.Maybe as Maybe
```

The piece in `()` after the module definition defines what you are exporting. Here we say "export all of `module A` along with the function `Maybe.fromMaybe`."